# Getting "Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat "C:\DumpStack.log.tmp" " in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been making an app using React Native and have started getting the above error.
It appeared after I tried to use an image in headerTitle while following the official guide on using React Navigation. I commented out the parts I added originally to see if the error would go away
This is my first app so I haven't got any experience with stuff like this happening unfortunately

I've looked at answers to people having the same problem and tried the suggestions like deleting the node_modules folder and then using "npm install", but to no avail :(
Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just got the same problem with my expo based react native app. Everything has been working fine for months, and now this error happens and the app won't run. Very strange. Reinstalling node_modules doesn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to a bad import statement in my JS code. I'm not using typescript but my IDE (Intellij) put in an include to a typescript file.

I'm using Expo, and oddly the app builds fine. It's the dev server that gives the chokidar error on startup. I eventually noticed in my android emulator there is a runtime error complaining about the missing node module which lead me to the bad import.

Once I removed that import statement everything was good.

The fact that chokidar gives error for the DumpStack.log.tmp file is very strange!